# 301 htaccess Redirect that will force?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Trying this again because I realize how very poorly I worded my original post.

I have a page, Product1.php, that is dynamic for populating my products from a database.

This is the rubric of my SEO-friendly urls:

```
http://www.example/category/subcategory/model_name-model_id/product_id
```

This is the original url with query string that it rewrites to:

```
http://www.example.com/Product1.php?=Product_ID=1
```

This is the rewrite function I have in htaccess that makes this happen:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^category/.*/.*/([0-9]+)$ Product1.php?Product_ID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, if a user manually-types in `http://www.example.com/Product1.php?=Product_ID=1` in the address bar, this is the one they still see. Moreover, it's the same for the search engine bots, which is dividing the value of my pages.

How do I write a 301 redirect that will **force the user and bot to see the SEO-friendly url only**, regardless of how they access the page? I have researched for days and various solutions I have tried give me only 404 or 500 errors.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: OK, looks like I can't invoke RewriteMap because I don't have access to my host's config files. (Need to upgrade our account to do so and employer is unwilling.) So will have to do a Rewrite Rule for each individual page, which is unfortunate but doable.

**But still need to find out how to force the redirect with causing 404 or 500 errors. Anyone?**

Comment: your code should never be outputting unfriendly urls in the first place. The `Product1.php?....` ugly ones should be purely an INTERNAL thing, existing only at the mod_rewrite level. Any links you output from PHP for the user to 'view' must always be the seo-friendly versions. If a user knows your system well enough to figure out what the "real" url is from the seo version, you've probably got bigger problems than just having some ugly urls out there.

Comment: Marc B: First of all, I am fully aware of this. However, I inherited the site from a previous developer whom didn't know SEO from OPEC. I am currently in the process of undoing all of her damage, which has been considerable. Secondly, can you possibly take a crack at answering my question? Thanks

Comment: you won't do this easily at the mod_rewrite level. while you can trivially detect someone coming in with a `/Product1.php?....` url, you'd either need a dedicated rule for **EVERY** id so you can redirect to the proper `/category/subcat` structure, or use a rewrite map to look up the values.

Comment: Marc B: A dedicated rule is a possibility I considered. But accounting for our ~300 products (which means ~300 rules), was trying to avoid. I know nothing about what a rewrite map is nor familiar with the term. I will see if I can look that up.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html  one of its features is being able to invoke an external script.

Comment: Just found that, thanks Marc B. Now gotta figure out how to create a working external function!

Answer (score 0):

I used a little trick adding an "Internal" parameter to a rule responsible for main rewrite, and the check of this parameter in the 301 redirect. The solution with environment variables is also allows to process requests where the parameters may be presented in any order.

```
RewriteEngine on

# perform collecting parameters from query string to an environment variables

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Category=([^&]+)
RewriteRule . - [E=category:%1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} SubCategory=([^&]+)
RewriteRule . - [E=subcategory:%1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Product_ID=([^&]+)
RewriteRule . - [E=productid:%1]

#...etc...

# give a right 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Product1.php
# make sure it's not an internal redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^Internal=1(.*)$
RewriteRule . /%{ENV:category}/%{ENV:subcategory}/%{ENV:productid}/? [L,R=301]

# now rewrite rule with the additional "Internal" parameter to label it as an internal redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
RewriteRule .* Product1.php?Internal=1&Category=%1&SubCategory=%2&Product_ID=%3 [L]
```

Thus, the following request

```
/Products1.php?Category=cat1&SubCategory=subcat1&Product_ID=321
```

will result in 301 redirect to

```
/cat1/subcat1/321/
```

and the appropriate page will be shown.

One more way is to remove the "Internal" trick and use another name of the script, Products2.php for example. I.e. you need something to distinguish external request from internal rewrite. to avoid infinite loop ("too much redirects" error).